# React build with env file

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build my react app but set a specific env file, right now it's going to the .production.env which is auto set on the build. I have tried the following but it's not working

```
"build:portal-customer-staging": "run-s cp:portal-customer --env=.env.development react:build ",
```

And my build

```
"build": "run-s build:_error exit:1",
"react:build": "react-scripts build",
```

Start

```
"react:start": "react-scripts start",
"start": "run-s start:_error exit:1",
```

Comment: follow this official doc https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables or maybe this would also help https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/environments-in-create-react-app.html

Comment: Following that and my app was created using create react app but the guide does not tell you how to set the env file on the build command the second link I tried that still did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd